# In Navicat SQL, how can I aggregate/create rows of data for a specific criteria?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, navicat

I am not sure what to call what I'm trying to do-

I made an example of what I want, specifically I want to search a column for a specific list of keywords, then I want to give each keyword a row of calculated cells. Here is a small example of what I'm trying to do!

:|

Left is the 'data,' right is how i'm trying to retrieve it.

!https://www.dropbox.com/s/0qny2nj8ln5uxng/Screenshot%202017-06-23%2017.01.12.png?dl=0!

I'm struggling! Not sure how/where to specify how to it!

```
 Select        
        Count(Distinct animal),  
        COUNT(DISTINCT post_id)AS post_count,
        Avg(age), 
        Avg(weight)
     From animal_database
WHERE(strpos(lower(animal),'dog'))>0
```

Etc. for 'cat' and 'Lizard'